# Using GitHub Desktop for Windows and Origin on GitHub got confused about the default branch

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I'm not certain what happened. Somehow "main" didn't get set as the default branch at the origin. It got set to an old branch that I've long since moved beyond. Though I see in the settings where I can switch the default branch, GitHub presents a big, scary warning that says:

"Changing your default branch can have unintended consequences that can affect new pull requests and clones."

What's the actual danger here? Or is there a way to just recreate the origin repository at GitHub from my local repository? This is just a personal thing that I'm working on. No worries about collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real issue in your case, for a personal repository.

You can use a [`gh repo edit --default-branch main`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit) (using the GitHub CLI `gh`, to [be installed first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)), if executed from your local repository folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. I did it the easy way; backed up my directory before I did anything (just to be sure), and then just changed the default directory from the settings page on GitHub, and all seems to be fine.

Comment: @thewatcheruatu "changed the default directory", you meant "changed the default branch"?